# RTL8822BE wifi card not turning on in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: wireless

I don't know what the problem is.

I did the following command:

```
sudo  lshw -C network
```

and found my Wifi Adapter to be disabled even though I never turned it off from Windows to Ubuntu

```
*-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 00
       serial: 28:3a:4d:3b:94:c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8822be driverversion=5.0.0-13-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:144 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a4300000-a430ffff
```

Then

I did

```
ip link set dev wlp7s0 up
```

and got from `sudo  lshw -C network`

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 00
       serial: 28:3a:4d:3b:94:c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8822be driverversion=5.0.0-13-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:144 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a4300000-a430ffff
```

but when I do `ip link sho | grep w`

I get:

```
4: wlp7s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
```

I can't turn on the wifi from the settings and not sure how I can troubleshoot further. Ethernet is working fine.

I have an Lenovo Legion Y7000.

Any help would be appreciated. I tried reinstalling ubuntu, but that didn't help. I tried downloading the drivers like solutions for <=18.04 used to do, but that didn't help either

Comment: Were you able to fix this?